# Plotly parallel coordinates plot lines not appearing in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-python

I’m running plotly-python version 4.7.0 in Python 3.6.9 on Ubuntu 18.04 and am currently trying to play with the parallel coordinates plots in the plotly.com tutorial [here](https://plotly.com/python/parallel-coordinates-plot/).

I’m running into display issues. Specifically in that the grids and key will display but the lines will not. See below:
[image]

This is the resulting plot if I send the visualization to browser and also when run in a Jupyter notebook. I thought I may have a package configuration issue, but when I simply view the website (again [here](https://plotly.com/python/parallel-coordinates-plot/)) on Ubuntu 18.04, the plots look similar to above. Which leads me to wonder about Ubuntu 18.04 compatibility.

I have run with the same configurations listed in the first sentence on several other plotly plot types and they run as expected but when running any parallel coordinates plot (generated in both `express` and `graph_objects`, the lines are missing. Also, when attempting to view any parallel coordinates plots on the website (on Ubuntu 18.04; the plots on the website display as expected on Windows 10), the lines are missing. So, in summary, my issue here appears to perhaps be a global operating system issue than it seems to be a Python configuration issue. But I could be wrong - my web search on this has resulted in finding no related issues.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.